# Jboss with apache2 : anything called on port 8080 should be redirected to 80

Tags: jboss, port

In my environment Jboss5 is configured with apache2 on same physical server. so

1. http ://my.domain.com:80/user/login ->Application login page
2. http ://my.domain.com:8080/user/login -> Application login page
3. http ://my.domain.com:8080/ -> Jboss Management console.

Now,  my actual requirement is to anything called on port 8080 should be redirected to 80.

1. http ://my.domain.com:80/user/login -> http ://my.domain.com/user/login -> Application login page [Working fine for now]
2. http ://my.domain.com:8080/user/login -> http ://my.domain.com/user/login -> Application login page
3. http ://my.domain.com:8080/ -> http ://my.domain.com/user/login -> Application login page.

What I did so far is, updated ROOT.war/index.html by meta forwarding to Application login page, i fixed point# 3 virtually somehow; bu not correct!! Do we have any idea!!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a servlet filter that check, which port the application is running. If it is running on port 8080, you send a response.sendDirect() to the correct port.

You need to configure the servlet filter in the web.xml file.

EDIT:
If you don't have the freedom to change the web.xml file, I would suggest you to resort to best practice, that is to let only one way to expose the application, that is through the port 80. You can block port 8080 from the external network from firewall so that all traffic goes through port 80.
It's best to let the apache2 do its job, as the reverse proxy server all the time. It is also useful in case you want to do load balancing later.

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks for reply!! This is true but here i some restriction i.e. jboss is contained under BPM-tool and we don't have much liberty to write/update web.xml in any way. Could we do it on configuration level!!

Comment: I think you'd better resort to use port 80 only and block port 8080 from outside (through firewall). How to set firewall depends on what OS you are in.

Comment: Hi Daniel, well not sure can we do it or not as there are four cluster servers, two of them having jboss instance and are being referenced by remaining two bpm engines. Blocking 8080 will cause non-functioning of  BPM engines!!

Comment: Since the BPM engines are known, your firewall should be able to select which packet are not originated from those BPM engines, and block/drop them, letting go the connection from only those 2 BPM engines.
I would do that, and possibly exposing the admin console from internal, and blocking the admin console from the reverse proxy if remote admin access not required.